# Multi-argument template functions, overloading and ambiguity errors

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I'm writing a some kind of conversion operator, and I want to use it like that:

```
SomeType a;
AnotherType b = conv<AnotherType>(a);
```

First, I write the base (default) function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline T conv(const U& a)
{
    return T(a);
}
```

Full specialization (or a non-template overload) is not a problem, however, when I want to do something like that:

```
template <typename T>
inline Point<T> conv(const Ipoint& p)
{
    return Point<T>(p.x, p.y);
}
```

I can't write any more conversion functions from the Ipoint (to the FunkyPoint< T > for example) due to ambiguity, and I end up with an awkward usage:

```
Ipoint a;
Point<double> b = conv<double>(a); //ugly!
//Point<double> b = conv<Point<double> >(a); //I want that, but it (obviously) does not compile.
```

Is there any way of doing it nicely?

Comment: Why not override the constructor or cast operator?

Comment: Because I do not have access to above mentioned structs (Ipoint/Point< T >).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the body in a class template and then you can partially specialize:

`template < typename T, typename U >
struct convert
{
  static T apply(U const& u) { return T(u); }
};`

template < typename T, typename U >
T conv(U const& u) { return convert<T,U>::apply(u); }

template < typename T >
struct convert<Point<T>, Ipoint>
{
  static Point apply(Ipoint const& u)
  {
    return Point(u.x, u.y);
  }
};

Should work but is untested.